# Develop with SQL Server and change to PostgreSQL later

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2, postgresql-11

I need to build an application with ASP.Net Core 2.2 MVC, EF Core and use SQL Server Local db during development.

However, when ready to deploy the app, I'd like to include the dependencies of PostgreSQL 11 into the project and point the project to use PostgreSQL rather than SQL Server .

Is this approach a viable approach that I can easily swap one database to another using EF Core or should I start with PostgreSQL from start?

Thank you in advance.

..Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a viable approach, but you can't use any SQL Server or PostgreSQL-specific features.

If you intend your program to continue to support both databases, then keep developing in either, but be aware of not using SQL Server specific features.

If you only indent to use PostgreSQL in the future, then you should develop using it. It is free, so you can easily install a local version for development.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your point is well taken. But the essence of my question was, from EF point of view, does it matter which DB is being used, if I ONLY interact with DB through EF?

Comment: It depends how you interact with the db through EF

Comment: Andreas was right. You need to start with PostgreSQL from the get go.
I created a ASP.Net Core 2.2 with Authentication, where VS17 created me a base solution with the default Local SQL and created the first migration based on SQL Server. Then I changed the settings to use EF for PostgreSQL and tried to run update-database I got a bunch of errors related to the syntax to create tables using migrations.
I then deleted all the migration files generated by VS and ran add-migrations using PosgreSQL drivers and it created me a new migration and when I did update-database, it properly works.